# Passing jstl's foreach varStatus into javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, jstl

is this possible?

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${requestScope.data}" varStatus="count">

<script>
myFunction(false,[]) // this is where i want to pass the `varStatus` on 2nd argument 
</script>

</c:forEach>
```

i've tried putting like :

```
myFunction(false,${count.index});
myFunction(false,<c:out value="${count.index}"></c:out>);
```

none of those worked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ${count.index} works for me. What output did you get?

Comment: @rickz says undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these tests. They all work for me. But, using the name "count for varStatus is confusing.   "count" is the name of the current 1-based iteration count in the LoopTagStatus interface.

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="a,b,c" varStatus="count">
    myFunction(false,${count.index}) <br/>
</c:forEach>

<c:forEach var="list" items="a,b,c" varStatus="status">
   myFunction(false,${status.index}) <br/>
</c:forEach>

<c:forEach var="list" items="a,b,c" varStatus="status">
    my Function(false,${status.count}) <br/>
</c:forEach>

<c:forEach var="list" items="a,b,c" varStatus="count">
    my Function(false,${count.count}) <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: why is that it seems that i can't use a direct javascript on my jsp page..eclipse gives me an error when i do that without putting `myFunction()` inside a `<script>` tag

Comment: I didn't use eclipse for my tests. I used Tomcat by itself. I was testing the JSTL code. Anyway, can't you just place the opening script tag above all the JSTL and the closing script tag below all the JSTL?

Comment: It's also giving me error. i also can't seem to use JSTL inside `<script>` tag

Comment: You need to find a Eclipse expert. Ask a question with the Eclipse tag.